# Why can't I reach methods of inner class in java?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, inner-classes

I have a structure similar to this:

```
 class OuterClass{
        AnimatorListener sth;
        public OuterClass(){
             sth = new InnerClass();
        }
        public class InnerClass implements AnimatorListener{
             public InnerClass(){}
             public void doSomething(){}
             //assuming animator listener methods implemented
        }
        public void tryingToDoSomething(){
             sth.doSomething();   //I cannot use this, simply it is not seen by eclipse.
        }
    }
```

Why cant I call `doSomething()` method of `sth` object while I am `tryingToDoSomething()` ?

Comment: mind the brackets `()` in your constructor for OuterClass

Comment: So what's the error message reported, when you implement this correction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object `sth` belongs to class `AnimatorListener` but it should belong to `InnerClass`. Hope this helps, happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

change your constructer syntax. It is wrong

```
public OuterClass{
         sth = new InnerClass();
    }
```

change this to

```
public OuterClass(){
         sth = new InnerClass();
    }
```

Comment: yes you are right, my mistake, it was just like you said in my codes.

Comment: your answer is just a correction which you should do by using "edit" button. It is still not a solution to my problem.

Comment: then there must be a problem, because I can edit problems at least with a confirmation.